# Quais são as vantagens de utilizar um current status nas aplicações?

Tags: projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos

É comum que durante determinados momentos uma aplicação saia do ar para uma atualização importante ou por algum motivo estejá lenta. Empresas que possui muitos serviços optam por utilizar um status que informa se um determinado serviços está funcionando normalmente como o [status gitlab](https://status.gitlab.com/) ou [status aws](https://status.aws.amazon.com/). Mas qual vantagem de utilizar esse recurso?

Ao meu ver é uma boa mostrar para o cliente que o serviço está ou não disponivel, mas para uma equipe que gerencia e desenvolve possui alguma vantagem? Não acho nenhuma informação de sobre esse conteudo, mas sinto que isso tem uma importancia muito grande para uma gerencia de projetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esses serviços de monitoramento das quais você se refere são na verdade a base de toda SRE (Site Reliability Engineering).

Resumidamente, nenhum sistema é imune a falhas. E à medida que a arquitetura de software evoluiu de aplicações monolíticas para aplicações distribuídas na nuvem, mais complexos e propenso a erros ficaram os processos de deploy e manutenção desses serviços em produção.

E a SRE tem como objetivo aumentar a confiabilidade dos serviços, automatizar os processos de deploy, monitorar os serviços, coletar estatísticas da saúde da aplicação, antever problemas que possam prejudicar a performance da aplicação, projetar mecanismos de tolerância à falhas e reagir rapidamente caso algum problema venha a acontecer.

> Se você não consegue monitorar um serviço, você não sabe o que está acontecendo e, se você não sabe o que está acontecendo, seu serviço pode não ser confiável.

N. Murphy, J. Petoff, C.Jones, B. Beyer - Site Reliability Engineering

E ao disponibilizar esses serviços de monitoramento publicamente, você aumenta a transparência da organização, você justifica os investimentos em engenharia com estatísticas, e você aumenta confiança que os usuários possuem em seus serviços.